# Public Maven and OBR repositories for open source projects

Tags: java, maven, repository, osgi, obr

I've been working on a small Java project centered around Apache Sling and other technologies (some of the other supporting technologies are open source, and some aren't).

I want to share a bundle and a maven archetype from some easily accessible repo.

Are there certain public repo's I should look at that support this type of thing? I am moving the project to github, though I dont think it has any inherent maven repo support built into it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is entirely open source, then you can use the public Sonatype OSS Respository.

I've successfully used this for hosting some small OSS libraries before.

Comment: +1 Exactly what the OP is looking for.  Only annoying part is that your GAV's groupId needs to be based on the SCM hosting URL

Comment: This repo looks spot on. The code I am sharing is all open source (written by me) -- the only non-OOS aspects are some dependencies in the pom.xml. thanks again.

Comment: Guide: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide